# How to retain bootstrap wizard step even on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using bootstrap wizard to get information from students. This form (wizard) is 12 steps long with average of 8 fields in each step. Completing the form (wizard) takes approx 20 minutes.

Now the problem:

A user is adding the data into the fields and moving on to next step clicking the next button. He is almost on the 8th, 9th or 10th steps and by mistake or for any other reason (like connectivity, slow network, etc) he is forced to refresh the page, the wizard starts again on step one. This is annoying. Now I want the page refresh to retain the step the user was on. How to accomplish this?

Please also suggest, if there is another option to use instead of using bootstrap wizard which can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this:

I switched to another component having the feature to store the state. Its "jQuery-Steps" (https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps). In this component there is an inbuilt behavior "saveState" which stores the current step into a cookie. So the step is retained even on page refresh.

This a very useful feature for forms having many steps and many fields.

Comment: same thing not possible in Bootstrap wizard?

Comment: What about my question on [Using Step Wizard in Application Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753630/using-step-wizard-in-application-form)? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the browser local storage to save the last step and the data entered. On page loading you can read the storage and restore the wizard state.
If the wizard is finished, delete the storage.
See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

**Note:** Name/value pairs are always stored as strings. Remember to convert them to another format when needed!

So you can make a function to save an object in JSON format and another function to retrieve it.

```
saveObjLocalStorage = function (key, obj) {
    if (window && window.localStorage) {
        try {
            window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj));
        } catch (ignore) {
        }
    }
};

getLocalStorageObj = function (key, defaultObj) {
    if (window && window.localStorage) {
        try {
            var storedFields = window.localStorage.getItem(key),
                obj;
            if (storedFields) {
                obj = JSON.parse(storedFields);
                return obj;
            }
        } catch (ignore) {
        }
    }
    return defaultObj;
};
```

For your concrete case, I think you have to use the events of the wizard plugin, evaluate the entries and pass an object to the function. The object could be something like this (it is up to you):

```
{
  currentStep: 'tab1',
  entriesTab0: {
    lastname: 'Doe',
    firstname: 'John',
    likeJavaScript: true
  },
  entriesTab1: {}
}
```

Example:

```
// store the entries in this object
var entries = getLocalStorageObj('myWizard', {
  currentStep: 0,
  entriesTab0: {},
  entriesTab1: {}
});
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
  onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
    entries.currentStep = index;      
  },
  onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {
    // I think index is the index of the next step.
    // On index === 1 evaluate entries on tab 0.
    if (index === 1) {
      entries.entriesTab0.lastname = $('#lastname').val();
      // evaluate other fields of tab 0
    } else if (index === 2) {
      // evaluate other fields of tab 1
    }
    saveObjLocalStorage('myWizard', entries);
  }
});
$('#lastname').val(entries.entriesTab0.lastname);
// init other fields
$('#rootwizard').find('li:eq(' + entries.currentStep + ') a').tab('show');
```

As Sean F said, you can also use `window.sessionStorage` instead. The storage will not be persistent and will be deleted when the user closes the specific browser tab.

**Note:** I never use the wizard and don't test this code. But it could give you a help to find the right way (I hope).

Comment: or use the sessionStorage object if you don't want the data to persist indefinitely

Comment: OK ! I am getting the idea. But can not workout how?

Comment: Which bootstrap plugin do you use? Can you share a link to this product? Thanks